# RPGLE How to use SETLL and READE to find duplicate records for a keyed field

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, freeform

Can someone give me an example of using SETLL and READE to find a duplicate record for a keyed field.

Currently the file I am working with has 3 keyed fields. The field I am looking for duplicates in is the second key in sequence.  I am not sure how to code this in free format, where I use READE and SETLL to find duplicate records.

```
/free
read filename;              

dow not %eof(filename);     


SETLL (XXPART)OUTPUTWORKFILE; 
IF NOT %EQUAL(OUTPUTWORKFILE);
write OUTPUTWORKFILE;  
enddo;
```

I know that I can't just jump to the second keyed field(XXPART), so I have to include the first keyed field (XXPLNT).  Just not sure how to do that in free form.  Also uncertain where I should put the reade.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you need a `reade` to do what you want. `setll` should be sufficient as long as you don't need anything from outfile. Notice that you can use a compound key with `setll`.

```
read filename;              
dow not %eof(filename);     
  setll (xxplnt: xxpart) outputworkfile;
  if not %equal(outputworkfile);
    write outputworkfile;
  endif;
  read filename;
enddo;
```

Answer (score 1):

@jmarkmurphy has a reasonable answer but I also think this is even easier using SQL if can.

```
select xxplnt, xxpart from filename
group by xxplnt, xxpart
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Mine writes a record for each key that doesn't exist in the output file. Your SQL selects one record for each key that has duplicates. The OP is not real clear on what they want. As the presented code won't compile, I made a guess. But these two solutions match up against different parts of the question

Comment: Yeah I had some confusion on the question as well.  I took it more to mean that he wanted to know which plant and part had duplicates but either one of our answers can be easily modified to get what he wants I hope.